# linq for js: how to get cartesian product of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq.js

I have an unpredictable number of arrays as showed on the picture below.

[image: arrays]

Using linq for js I would like to get a Cartesian product of these arrays ie.

```
{
    {AttributeTypeId: 10, AttributeId: 34, AttributeName: "b11  13-128"}
    {AttributeTypeId: 11, AttributeId: 56, AttributeName: "21/uk4"},
    {AttributeTypeId: 13, AttributeId: 69, AttributeName: "Boy"}
},
    {AttributeTypeId: 10, AttributeId: 33, AttributeName: "b10  13-128"},
    {AttributeTypeId: 11, AttributeId: 56, AttributeName: "21/uk4"},
    {AttributeTypeId: 13, AttributeId: 69, AttributeName: "Boy"}
},
{
    {AttributeTypeId: 10, AttributeId: 38, AttributeName: "G01  13-102"},
    {AttributeTypeId: 11, AttributeId: 56, AttributeName: "21/uk4"},
    {AttributeTypeId: 13, AttributeId: 69, AttributeName: "Boy"}
},
{
    {AttributeTypeId: 10, AttributeId: 34, AttributeName: "b11  13-128"},
    {AttributeTypeId: 11, AttributeId: 54, AttributeName: "19/uk3"},
    {AttributeTypeId: 13, AttributeId: 69, AttributeName: "Boy"}
}
....
etc.
```

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please see [ask] in the Help Center.  This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

For every array you want in the result, just add a select many.

```
var result = Enumerable.from(data[0]).selectMany(a =>
    Enumerable.from(data[1]).selectMany(b =>
        Enumerable.from(data[2]).select(c =>
            [a, b, c]
        )
    )
).toArray();
```

This is the equivalent to the query syntax:

```
from a in data[0]
from b in data[1]
from c in data[2]
select [a, b, c]
```

Comment: thanks you ! unfortunately I can't up vote your answer as I'm a new user

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following simple two-line function to make a Cartesian product of any number of arrays:

```js
// cartesian product of arrays
const cartesian = (...arrays) => arrays.reduce((a, b) => 
  [].concat(...a.map(a => b.map(b => [].concat(a, b)))));

// usage example
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b'];
const arr3 = [true, false];

console.log(cartesian(arr1, arr2, arr3));
```